# Can back EMF from a solenoid trip a circuit breaker?

Tags: solenoid, back-emf

I am working on an ignition circuit right now in a Cessna 172, the issue is that when the ignition switch is turned to engage the starter, the circuit breaker supplying power from the bus through the switch to the starter relay is tripping. Prior to this a new solenoid was installed, however the diode was omitted as the installer broke it. Now, whenever the start position is engaged with the ignition switch the circuit breaker trips.

The placement of the diode is in between the 'C' and 'D' studs in the image. Again, this is where it *was*. Now there is simply a wire between the two without a diode. To my knowledge the back EMF can cause arcing in the ignition switch, but is it possible it would cause the breaker to trip?
[image]

Here is an image of a properly installed solenoid that works, the heat shrink covers a diode assembly. I could provide further schematics but I feel like the question is mainly theoretical and shouldn't be how to fix my exact specific problem. Let me know if schematics of the system would help answer this general question, however.
[image]

Comment: which breaker http://avitmedia.aero.und.edu/c172sElectrical/images/elecbg.jpg

Comment: Wait - the diode was replaced with a wire?  If so, turning the ignition switch on is a direct short to ground.  Even replacing a missing diode with a (ceramic disc) capacitor would be better than nothing. But ideally, the diode should be replaced with an equivalent.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 A standard trip-free circuit breaker (5A, relay circuit is supposed to have 850mA).

Comment: @rdtsc See this is what I thought. However what does the diode do to prevent this direct short to ground anyway? When I first saw it I wondered why the current from the switch to the relay here does not immediately go to ground. Does this diode prevent that in some way? The image posted is a proper and working solenoid installation. The one that doesn't work is exactly the same but the switch to ground stud wire does not contain the heat-shrinked diode assembly. Does the diode prevent a direct path to ground in some way?

Comment: Okay, as I suspected opening the wire between the C and D stud causes the starter to work properly (obviously it's not going back into service until the diode assembly is installed to prevent switch damage). But can someone explain to me why this diode doesn't still allow a direct short to ground? Is it requiring a current buildup before it can pass the diode? Apologies as I am a Comp. sci guy and not super well versed on circuits..

Comment: Wait, somebody modified the ignition circuit of a small plane, to the point that now the circuit is no longer working and... You are looking for help on a website?

Comment: @SredniVashtar The schematics and IPC do not mention a diode assembly. I researched on why they are used but the users on here filled in serious gaps in my knowledge. Ideal? No, but I appreciate you guys helping me out here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solenoid and ignition circuit with proper diode would look something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5lxvk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note the diode is wired in parallel to the solenoid actuation coil. As the ignition switch closes, a current builds up in the solenoid coil. This current causes magnetism, which attracts the switch part of the solenoid, which then starts the engine starter motor spinning.

Once the engine starts, the ignition switch is released or opened. The solenoid coil however, still has stored current (and magnetism) inside it.  That has to go somewhere.  With the diode in place, that current is recirculated within the solenoid coil, and safely dissipates in a second or two.

Current can only pass through a diode in the "forward" direction - that is, from the "arrow" or anode side to the "plate" or cathode side. Therefore, hitting the ignition switch does nothing to the diode (no current flows through it), as the switch current comes from the *cathode* side.  And, current in a coil keeps flowing in the same direction.  It's only when the ignition switch opens, that the current from the coil is able to recirculate into the protection diode, traveling from anode to cathode, and back to itself.

Without the protection diode, the solenoid coil would try to (instantly) dump all of that stored energy across anything it could (the now-open ignition switch), causing an arc there.  This is bad for many reasons (wear and tear, fire hazard, creates RF interference...), especially in an aircraft.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8T7Bp.png)</sup>

But if the protection diode were replaced with a wire, it would look like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBrpDz.png)</sup>

It should be clear that closing the ignition switch would directly connect the battery positive terminal to it's negative, causing a large current to flow and the circuit breaker (not shown) to open.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you very much. I had my idea of how the diode was installed backwards and that makes sense. It also makes sense why it re-circulates through the diode and coil as opposed to trying to go through the switch. Thanks much for the explanation and pictures!

Comment: It is clear the switch applies +v to the solenoid coil and logically the 1A diode for flyback on a 1A or 2A coil is adequate.  But why did the power diode fail when it's rating is adequate?  It is hardly ever used and only active when the starter solenoid switches off.  So why did the breaker trip and why did the POWER DIODE FAIL?    Hint does diode location matter if it stays logically across the coil in reverse bias.?  Does switch bounce matter?  Is the solenoid coil 12W or 24W?  Does that matter?

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 The diode in this case did not fail. The previous workers broke the diode when installing a new solenoid and decided to install a normal wire in its place. This diode is not shown in the schematics nor the parts catalogue. I wasn't familiar with the systems so I had to figure out that it should be a diode and not a wire. My logic thought that if the diode was preventing back emf then the diode would not allow current in the direction of the switch (which is poor logic as this would cause a short). I removed the wire and it works, and I've purchased a diode to install.

Comment: So, I apologize for such a rudimentary question that lacked some foundational sanity checks. One user hinted I should not be using a website to ask this problem, but again the manuals and parts catalogue made no reference...I found a diode to purchase via the solenoid manufacturer and you guys really helped me understand the issue here even if it was very simple. The mechanics set the battery on fire by shorting the starter to ground and, after destroying the existing components, installed the new ones improperly. Manuals couldn't fill all the gaps here but it's solved thanks to your help!

Comment: @Suomalinen my point is that I thought that sensible repairs such as this on a small plane should be done by certified and qualified personnel only. A mechanic that sets a battery on fire and a user who is not knowledgeable in electronics do not appear to be that kind of professional figures. There is nothing wrong in asking questions, but it looked like this plane was not properly serviced.

Comment: @SredniVashtar I am FAA certified to work on the aircraft and release it to service, I just work as a programmer now. It was properly fixed and returned to service. I'm sorry that your ideal world doesn't contain people with gaps in their knowledge or those who make mistakes. I suspect this website would have far less practical use if that were the case, however.